# gitlab repositories not migrating to omnibus version

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am having trouble migrating gitlab repositories from manual version to omnibus version.

When I run:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get empty repositories!!

I even tried to copy them manually:

```
sudo cp -r /home/git/repositories/* /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/
sudo chown -R git:git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/*
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos
```

But still no luck, the files are there, but in the admin interface it says the repo is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're supposed to just copy stuff into the `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` directly.     But just for luck, did you try `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`?

Comment: Also try doing `sudo gitlab-ctl tail` while you browse those repositories and check what the logs say so we can better understand what's going on